# How to sort multidimensional array by value?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

**Original array:**

```
$resolutions =  array (
        "Desktop monitor" => array (
            //Standard 4:3
            "800x600" => "800x600",
            "1024x768" => "1024x768",
            "1600x1200" => "1600x1200",
            //Wide 16:10
            "960x600" => "960x600",
            "1280x800" => "1280x800",
            "1440x900" => "1440x900",
            "1680x1050" => "1680x1050",
            "1920x1200" => "1920x1200",
        ),
        "Apple" => array (
            "DeviceX" => "2048x1536",
            "DeviceY" => "1024x768",
        ),
);
```

**Wanted array:**

```
$resolutions =  array (
        "Desktop monitor" => array (
            "800x600" => "800x600",//Standard 4:3
            "960x600" => "960x600",//Wide 16:10
            "1024x768" => "1024x768",//Standard 4:3
            "1280x800" => "1280x800",//Wide 16:10
            "1440x900" => "1440x900",//Wide 16:10
            "1600x1200" => "1600x1200",//Standard 4:3
            "1680x1050" => "1680x1050",//Wide 16:10
            "1920x1200" => "1920x1200",//Wide 16:10
        ),
        "Apple" => array (
            "DeviceY" => "1024x768",
            "DeviceX" => "2048x1536",
        ),
);
```

**What I have tried:**

```
foreach ($resolutions as $screen => $resolution) { 
        foreach($resolution as $key => $val) {
            $newarray[$key] = $row[$val];
        }
        array_multisort($newarray, SORT_DESC, $resolution);
    }
```

I thought that I'm half way to end, but the code above gave me some non sense (for me), ie: first goes resolution 1024x768, then 1280x800, followed by 1440x900 and in the end is 800x600.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are sorting alphabetically. You will need to calculate the size of each resolution to sort them correctly. This will require writing a custom comparison function that calculate the resolution sizes and compare them.

```
foreach ($resolutions as &$resolution)
    uasort($resolution, function ($a, $b) { return array_product(explode('x', $a)) - array_product(explode('x', $b)); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick hack looking specifically for the `Desktop monitor` array key. `ksort` will sort by array key, but it doesn't sort well when you have an `x` in the middle of some numbers. Here's my solution:

- Loop through array
- Build new array with only first half of resolution as array key
- Use `ksort` to sort new array
- `array_walk` new array to create output array which looks like original
- output original:

https://eval.in/71433

You could do the same thing for other arrays inside your original array e.g. `Apple` by using the **value** instead of the **key** as the resolution, and put the `array_walk` etc inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at what you've put there, two things stand out:

- You're looping through the outer array and sorting a single-dimensional array using multisort; I would recommend just using asort().
- Not quite sure what's going on there with $resolutions being passed in as the thrid paramter. It wants an array of sort flags.

try:

```
foreach ($resolutions as $resolution) { 
        asort($resolution);
    }
```